# Finding the best univariate model

Tags: r, multiple-regression, linear-model

I have the response variable as Profit, and several predictor variables. I have made a multivariate linear model to represent this, and have also made univariate models for every individual predictor variable. How can I determine which univariate model best represents the actual model?

My idea was to subtract the p-value of a predictor in the multivariate model from the p-value in it's univariate model, but I am not sure that this is the correct way to do this.

How should I do it? I am using R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question, you could look at a correlation matrix with each variable correlated with the predictor.

You could also look at the adjusted R-squared of the whole model Vs each individual predictor. The best univariate R-squared is the highest.

I'd personally steer clear of a stepwise regression but it could point you in the direction of your answer. As for regressions in R, the code is fairly simple, I learned from and regularly used the below site as it also provides information around the assumptions in this type of model.

http://r-statistics.co/Linear-Regression.html

Comment: To hopefully clear up: There are 6 predictor variables. There is one model with ALL variables as predictors, and there are 6 other models with each of the predictor variables as the only predictor. I have been asked which of these models represent the model with all 6 predictors in best. If this is what you understood from the question, how would i do a correlation matrix with that? Also for the second method, is it the model with R squared closest to the R squared of the whole model?

Comment: To create the correlation matrix you can use the cor function e.g. corMatr <- cor(data)
Where data is your table of predictors and target. To your second point, for the multivariate model, you are looking at the adjusted R-squared. If for example this is 0.6 then 60% of the variation in the dependent variable is accounted for by your model. 
If you then create 2 univariate models with an R-squared of 0.1 - 10% and one with 0.02 - 2% you can see that one of the predictors is better than the other and closer to the multivariate model for explaining the variation in the dependent variable.

Comment: Instead of using a correlation matrix, could I calculate all of the correlations between response and each predictor separately and then obviously the higher the correlation, the better fit that univariate model is?

Comment: You could do but the correlation matrix shows this information. Also remember that your R value (your correlation coefficient) is a measure of the strength of the relationship between predictor and dependent variable. Your R-squared is a measure of effect size. Apologies for not being specific but you want the adjusted R-squared if you are working with a sample as R-squared is positively biased. It would be correct to say 'The higher the Adjusted R-squared the better the fit the model is'

Comment: So I should use R-squared in this case? I am using a whole data-frame as the data.

Comment: Use adjusted R-squared